# Dump Postgres database when space is tight?

Tags: postgresql, ssh, dump

Imagine this situation.  I have a server that has only 1 GB of usable space.  A Postgres database takes about 600MB of that (as per `SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('dbname'));`), and other stuff another 300MB, so I have only 100 MB free space.

I want to take a dump of this database (to move to another server).

Naturally a simple solution of `pg_dump dbname > dump` fails with a Quota exceeded error.

I tried to condense it first with `VACUUM FULL` (not sure if it would help for the dump size, but anyway), but it failed because of disk limitation as well.

I have SSH access to this server.  So I was wondering: is there a way to pipe the output of `pg_dump` over ssh so that it would be output to my home machine?

(Ubuntu is installed both on the server and on the local machine.)

Other suggestions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is.

On your local machine do something like:

```
ssh -L15432:127.0.0.1:5432 user@remote-machine
```

Then on your local machine you can do something like:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 15432 ...
```

This sets up a tunnel from port 15432 on your local box to 5432 on the remote one. Assuming permissions etc allow you to connect, you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you, it helped.  One correction: pg_dump will take `-p` option (lowercase) for port.

Comment: Thanks. That' the danger of typing on a Friday evening. Oh - you can of course tunnel a psql session in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

(if the machine is connected to a network) you can do everything from remote, given sufficient authorisation:

from your local machine:

```
pg_dump -h source_machine -U user_id the_database_name >>the_output.dmp
```

And you can even pipe it straight into your local machine (after taking care of user roles and creation of DBs, etc):

```
pg_dump -h ${ORIG_HOST} -U ${ORIG_USER} -d ${ORIG_DB} \
     -Fc --create | pg_restore -c -C | psql -U postgres template1
```

- pg_dump executes on the local (new) machine
- but it connects to the $ORIG_HOST as user $ORIG_USER to db $ORIG_DB
- pg_restore also runs on the local machine
- pg_restore is not *really* needed (here) but can come in handy to drop/rename/create databases, etc
- psql runs on the local machine, it accepts a stream of SQL and data from the pipe, and executes/inserts it to the (newly created) database
- the connection to `template1` is just a stub, because psql insists on being called with a database name
- if you want to build a command-pipe like this, you should probably start by replacing the stuff after one of the `|` pipes by `more` or `less`, or redirect it to a file.
- You might need to import system-wide things (usernames and tablespaces) first